# On Excel is there a way to change a value entered into a cell, within the same cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, I would like to enter an amount of money in one currency and have Excel automatically convert it into another (in my case, enter Euros but display GBP).

Comment: You will need VBA in a worksheet_Change event.

Comment: And do not forget to prevent chain Worksheet_Change firing.